# Store selector (not switcher) inside phtml file

Tags: multistore, phtml

Is there any method to call store selector inside phtml file? I found only store switcher but I need store selector multiselect options.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with simple solution.

I copied file `app/design/adminhtml/default/template/sotre/switcher.phtml` to my `phtml` file, then I just put `multiple="multiple"` into select tag and did some other tiny changes.

I also created own block which extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Store_Switcher` to get a list of already selected websites.

In this way I transformed store switcher into store multi-select.